# I want to fetch images from folder one after another using flask and display it on front end in same container with certain interval of time

Tags: html, flask

**app.py**

In this code I am trying to fetch images from folder one after another on same container the problem is images are not displaying on dashboard one after another after.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import os
app = Flask(__name__)
picfolder=os.path.join('static','photos')
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = picfolder
Allowed_Extensions=set(['png','jpg','jpeg','gif'])
@app.route("/")
def index():
    pic1=os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],"img1.JPG")
    imageList = os.listdir('static/photos/')
    imagelist = ['photos/DSC_0175.jpg/' + image for image in imageList]
    return render_template("index.html", imagelist=imagelist)
if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run()
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="videoSection">
        <div class="liveVideoContainer">
           <h3>Live</h3>
           {% for imagelist in imagelist %}
            <img src=" {{url_for('static',filename='imagelist' )}} " width="80" height="142">
           {% endfor %}
        </div>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "GET /static/imagelist HTTP/1.1" 404 -I am getting these error as i want to display the images on dashboard..please suggest me where i am going wrong.

Comment: I would suggest removing the quotes from `filename='imagelist'`. This is because you want to access the `imagelist` variable from the for loop instead of a string `'imagelist'`.

Comment: I made changes what u said it worked. Thank you